# Which connector type is this?

Tags: identification, connector, automotive, 12v

I'm looking for the bullet-type connector that is used with Tracer Power batteries. Here's the link for their version of it: https://www.tracerpower.com/bullet-bare-ends.html

I found a connector called "seadog" or "SAE", however, it is about twice the size in all dimensions. Tracer themselves also say it is an SAE -connector.

The dimensions of the connector are WxH = 14 mm x 7 mm and the "male" plug's dimension at it's widest is aroud 3.1 mm. The larger SAE connector that I had was at least 3.5 mm in diameter.

This is what the Tracer connector looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SAE DC connector is hermaphroditic which means there is no difference between the plug and socket.

Searching for "SAE Right angle connector" brings up other sellers of the product you linked to, but does not shed any light on the source of the connector itself.

As it seems to be an injection moulded part, there is a good chance you cannot buy these off the shelf - the whole assembly is moulded in the factory. Unless a solder cup version exists, your best bet is to find a cheap supplier of the cables and cut them to length.

Comment: _which means there is no difference between the plug and socket._ That's not what it means. You're conflating hermaphroditic (has both pins and sockets) with self-mate (mates to an identical connector). OP' s connector one is both. But may connectors are only hermaphroditic (e.g., a 3-pole SAE), and many are only self-mate (e.g, the a knife disconnect).